# Where can you find high resolution images of Android phones?

Tags: android

I'm looking for high res Android phone "shell" to more effectively visualize my Android apps.

For example, the Samsung Galaxy Vibrant:

http://www.samsung.com/us/system/consumer/product/sg/hi/89/sghi897zkaatt/SGH-I897ZKAATT_1_600.jpg

The problem here is that this image is very low resolution.  If you want to showcase your app in it's full resolution, you need a higher res shell.

A good example is this HTC Desire available from Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HTC_Desire_01.jpg

You can use this 'shell' to display your Android app in it's full resolution; and the shell itself is awesome quality.

So, I guess the main question is:  where can we find some high res front facing shots for new Android devices?   The HTC Desire is a tad dated now, it would be better to have a high res pics of any of these phones:

- Samsung Galaxy S Vibrant
- HTC T-Mobile G2
- Samsung Nexus S (not yet released as of this posting)

Comment: UPDATE: a contact from within HTC was nice enough to hook me up with an uber high res T-Mobile G2.   I'll post it when I get a chance sometime later.

Comment: If you don't find a good resource for this, please host the images on a site somewhere so others can benefit from your collecting!

Comment: No problem, just uploaded it to my blog (update): http://nerdbusiness.com/blog/high-resolution-android-phones-app-designers

Comment: Should this be asked here instead: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

There's a new Device [frame generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/device-frames.html) in the Android Asset Studio. It has the Nexus 1,S, Galaxy and Xoom.

Comment: Thats a nice feature. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The link is broken.  Can you update it, please?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/18/android-gui-psd-vector-kit/

This will help you visualise the apps within the hi-res phone of your choice. Or just use the 'generic' phone used in this file.

Comment: Thanks that's a good start!  Doesn't hurt to have some basic UI elements, however I am more focused on getting the high res 'shell' for the newest phones.

Answer (score 2):

If you need them for anything more than stills I would head over to [3D02](http://3d02.com/3d_model_index.aspx?OptSearchType=1&TxtKeyword=android)

Comment: Quite good designs really.

Answer (score 2):

Samsung (like most product manufacturers) maintains a press/news room website where the press can find high-resolution photos of their products from multiple different angles.

[Their mobile phones section is here](http://www.samsungusanews.com/index.jsp?menu=photos&album=3).

[Motorola has one too](http://mediacenter.motorola.com/imagelibrary/default.aspx?CSubjectId=20&MediaTypeId=1), as does [Sony Ericsson](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/corporate/press/pressreleases/medialibrary/phones).

The best way to find these (in my experience) is to search for the company name and "press gallery".

Be aware, there are often terms of use that may not be amenable to you.